# Cheer up with this riddle

Tags: riddle, poetry, limerick

> My prefix weighs little, but never has mass;
>   My suffix might, for a whole language, pass;
>   But to me append,
>   One more suffix at end;
>   And scramble my innards so I'm longer at last

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> **LIGHTEN**

*My prefix weighs little, but never has mass;*

> Something which is **LIGHT** 'weighs little'. Also, light (the noun) has no mass.

*My suffix might, for a whole language, pass;*

> **EN** is an abbreviation for 'English', often in language settings on computer programs and websites.

*But to me append,*
*One more suffix at end;*
*And scramble my innards so I'm longer at last*

> Add the suffix ER to get LIGHTENER then anagram (scramble) the inner letters to get *LENGTHIER*, meaning 'longer'.

As for the title:

> 'Lighten up' and 'cheer up' can be synonyms, as in how a drop of sunlight can 'lighten up' a drab room - or as in 'Lighten up, dude!'

Comment: I'm new, but you're quickly becoming one of my favorite answerers on this site. I couldn't have explained this riddle better myself. Well done!

Comment: Thanks @anodyne - that's a great compliment :) I hope you're enjoying your journey into Puzzling - there's plenty to enjoy here!